# How would I go about connecting a css folder to an HTML file?

Tags: html, css

Alright so this is my first post, and I'm sorry to bother with such a stupid question but I was wondering how would I go about writing a file path to a folder with my css in to and connect it to my HTML folder.

Would it be like ./FOLDER-Name/Style.css

because I have tried that but it hasn't worked. Someone please help, Thank You.

Comment: Share what you have tried in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be like this

```html
<link href="FOLDER-Name/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

example taken from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) :

```
<link href="/media/examples/link-element-example.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

You just have to replace the href string to whatever path leads to your css file. I recommend using a relative path.